# Returning String from method in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to return the input from the user (inputname) from the method Dialog so that it can be printed in the method Print later, but I am getting the error message "exercise4.java:85: error:  expected

```
public static String Dialog(inputname) //asks user about station and prints result"
    public static void main (String args [] )
    {
        Dialog(); // asks user about station and returns answer
        Print(); // prints station information

        System.exit(0);
    }
    // END Main method

    public static String Dialog(inputname) //asks user about station 
    {
        String inputname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What station would you like information about?");

        return inputname;
    }



    public static void Print() //prints information
    {
        System.out.println("The name of the station is "+ inputname);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change method to 
`public static String Dialog() `

Comment: You should specify of what type is `inputname`, or remove it (as you aren't using it). Also, method `Print()` uses a variable `inputname`, but does not have access to a variable with that name.

Comment: When declaring a method you need to define the types of the parameters you are able to pass. You did not do that with `(inputname)` and I also don't really understand what the point of that parameter is anyway.

Comment: as a sidenote, your `void` method might accept the blank `return` but it´s rarely used and pretty useless here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main (String args [] ) {
    String inputname = Dialog(); // asks user about station and returns answer
    Print(inputname); // prints station information

    System.exit(0);  
}
// END Main method



public static String Dialog() {//asks user about station 
    String inputname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What station would you like information about?");
    return inputname;
}



public static void Print(String inputname) {//prints information
    System.out.println("The name of the station is "+ inputname);
    return;
}
```

You must do two things:

1. Store Dialog()'s returned inputname in a variable.
2. Hand that value over to Print().

What you miss is that you loose the user's data as you don't store it in a variable.

Comment: You need to remove `inputname` from `Dialog(inputname)`

Comment: Not sure why he should "try this": `public static String Dialog(inputname)` as it's not a valid java method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
public static String Dialog(inputname) //asks user about station 
{
   String inputname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What station would
```

...

And:

```
public static void Print() //prints information
{
  System.out.println("The name of the station is "+ inputname);
```

The variable `inputname` is a **local** variable within the first method. It is simply **not** visible anywhere else - especially outside of that method. The simple solution:

```
 public static void printName(String name) ...
```

and then

```
   printName(getNameFromDialog())
```

I took the freedom to **rename** your methods to be A) following Java conventions and B) tell the reader what they actually do.

Alternatively, you could declare a *static* field within your class, and have both methods using that field (instead of using local variables resp. parameters).